# Database configuration in Kali Linux

Tags: kali-linux, metasploit

Whenever I search for an exploit in msfconsole, it shows a message `[*] module` `database cache not built yet` and after 1-2 minutes it shows search results,  same database problem with armitage when I issue a command :

```
root@kali# service postgresql start
```

and then armitage it again shows a database misconfiguration error.  How to resolve?

[image: Metasploit error part 1]
[image: Metasploit error part 2]

Comment: What is the actual error you're seeing?

Comment: Here i am providing two links since i am not allowed to upload a screenshot due to insufficient reputations.                                             https://i.stack.imgur.com/f0Rlk.jpg  (for armitage)                                       https://i.stack.imgur.com/bdihJ.jpg (for metasploit)

Comment: Did you try to run the suggested commands in the message box and/or tried to check the database.yml?

Comment: No,  in which directory I should check database. yml?

Comment: Should be somewhere in the metasploit directory. But did you simply run the init command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check whenever your metasploit is connected to the database, run the following command:

```
db_status
```

If metasploit is connected to the database, run the following command to rebuild the cache:

```
db_rebuild_cache
```

Rebuilding the cache takes some time.

Taken from: [Fix metasploit “Database not connected or cache not built”](http://www.dailysecurity.net/2013/05/11/fix-metasploit-database-not-connected-or-cache-not-built/)